# bootstrap modal not showing data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just stuck in bit awkward situation.I am using bootstrap modal to show form on my page.previously old data was getting retained each time I open the modal. so I added this line in my code

```
 $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body").html("");
});
```

Now first time it is showing proper data but second time onwards it is not showing anything in my model.  below is my model code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" id="closeTab" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">add holiday</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" id="holidayForm">
             <h3> <label id="addHoliday"><span class="label label-info">date</span></label>  </h3>

            <h3> <label id="holidayDetail"><span class="label label-info">description</span></label> </h3>
              <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" placeholder="description" type="text">
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="saveChanges" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is code pop up bootstrap

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    var clickId=$(this).attr('id');
    var myDate=clickId.toString().substr(0,2);
    var myMonth=clickId.toString().substr(2,4);
    $("#addHoliday").append("<h3><input type='text' name='newDate' disabled='disabled' id='newDate'value="+this_year+"-"+myMonth+"-"+myDate+"></input></h3>");
    $("#myModal").modal('show');


})
```

please let me know what is wrong

Comment: The $(".modal-body").html(""); is clearing out everything inside the .modal-body including  the addHoliday, so the next time you click the button, #addHoliday doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: then how to solve this if I remove that line old data was not being cleared after closing modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution...

To clear out the form fields, you can do something like this

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body #holidayForm input").val("");
});
```

You are appending a new input field every time the .clickMe click event is fired.  I would put that html code with the input fields in the .modal-body where you want it, and then  replace the appending to #addHoliday line to something like this..

```
$(".modal-body #holidayForm #newDate").val(this_year + "-" + myMonth + "-" + myDate);
$(".modal-body #holidayForm #inputlg").val("");
```

**UPDATE**

In reply to your comment, change the html of the #addHoliday in the modal-body to this.

```
         <h3> 
             <label id="addHoliday">
             <span class="label label-info">date</span>
             <h3><input type="text" name="newDate" id="newDate" value=""/></h3>
             </label>
         </h3>
```

This way you have one newDate input field, and the click event is updating that field in the .modal-body

Make sense?

Comment: if I am replacing appending line then its not showing date field at all

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abbottmw/ymdtbLgr/) of what I am talking about.